# awk - Print all values with a suffix

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I want to use awk to print all values in a delimited string with a static suffix appended to each one.

**Input:**

```
stack,over,flow
```

**Delimiter:**

```
Comma
```

**Output:**

```
stack suffix, over suffix, flow suffix
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' -vpre="prefix" -vsuf="suffix" \
    '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) $i = pre $i suf; print }'
```

For the input

```
unix,and,linux
```

this would produce

```
prefixunixsuffix,prefixandsuffix,prefixlinuxsuffix
```

The `awk` program modifies each field in a loop by adding a prefix and a suffix.  The prefix and suffix strings are passed into the `awk` programs through assignments to the `pre` and `suf` variables on the command line.

To add a space as prefix and the string `suffix` (with an initial space) as suffix, you would use

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' -vpre=" " -vsuf=" suffix" \
    '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) $i = pre $i suf; print }'
```

which produces

```
 unix suffix, and suffix, linux suffix
```

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda, its awesome, and one more doubt, If I don't want the comma, how can I remove that? like ```stack suffix over suffix flow suffix``` or replace with some other value

Comment: @SQLadmin Modify the output field separator (`OFS`) on the command line. For example, remove `-v OFS` completely to get space-separated output.

Answer (score 2):

Another Awk variant - making use of the internal output separators to avoid an explicit loop:

```
awk -F, -v s=' suffix' 'BEGIN{OFS= s FS " "; ORS= s RS} {$1=$1} 1'
```

ex.

```
echo 'stack,over,flow' | awk -F, -v s=' suffix' 'BEGIN{OFS= s FS " "; ORS= s RS} {$1=$1} 1'
stack suffix, over suffix, flow suffix
```

For space separated output you can append the default output field separator to the suffix

```
$ echo 'stack,over,flow' | awk -F, -v s=' suffix' 'BEGIN{OFS= s OFS; ORS= s RS} {$1=$1} 1'
stack suffix over suffix flow suffix
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F , '{print $1" suffix",  $2" suffix",  $3" suffix"}' OFS=", " suffix
```

`awk -F ,` Sets the field separator as ,

`print $1" suffix",` and so on and so forth prints a space and then suffix after the value

`OFS=", "` Sets the output field separator as a comma with a space.

Output:

```
 stack suffix, over suffix, flow suffix
```

Comment: Hey @Nasir, thanks, but in my case, there can be multiple values in input. So we need to use -F to get all values print with suffix.I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: @SQLadmin The other answer works better. In the future, you need to specify that information in your question so that it can be accounted for.